# How can I get date object from a bootstrap-datetime-picker plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I am trying to utilize [tempusdominus-datetimepicker-3](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-3/Options/) to create a date-time picker in my html-forms.

However, I need to be able to get the selected date from it. The plugin has an option called [date](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-3/Options/#date) which according to the document should return a moment object or null. Here is what the document say about this option

> Returns the component's model current date, a `moment` object or `null` if
>   not set

However, I am struggling to access the `date` option.

Also from the doc

> Note All options are accessed via the `data` attribute e.g.
>   `$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker(OPTION, ARGUMENT)`

So I tried the following to access the date option.

```
from = $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker('date');
from = $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker('data', 'date');
from = $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker('data').date;
from = $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker(function(e){
    return e.date;
});
```

But none of the above is returning the object. How can I access the date object?

I would think a nice plugin like this one will have more readable option like `getDate()`, `setDate(date)`, `getFomat()` and `setFormat(...)` etc; or event examples, which should eliminate questions like this one, but unfortunately it does not.

Comment: I think you can acces on html input so i dont know that would you like to use as moment element then you can use i o change event then can reach via params e.date as moment cloned element

Comment: I would think there is a simple way date object which should be a `moment` object which is what I am looking for.

Comment: `$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker('date')` works for me, can you provide a snippet or a fiddle showing the issue?

Comment: @Jaylen did yo managed to solve the problem you were facing.

Comment: this is the worst plugin ever

Answer (score 17):

Here is the correct code to access events :

```
$(function() {
   $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
   $('#datetimepicker').on("change.datetimepicker", function (e) {
      console.log(e.date);
   });
 });
```

You can get date using this too :

```
var date = $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker('viewDate')
```

Complete fiddle to manipulate the date : https://jsfiddle.net/10xzksm0/2/

Comment: This will catch the date on the change event. This is different than what I need. I need to simple set a variable to the data outside an event.

Comment: You said : "However, I need to be able to get the selected date from it.". There is no binding, you only can get date from an event. It's jQuery, not Angular...

Comment: Updated answer, but anyway, you need to call it using event functions.

Comment: In my case, change event it is triggered twice every time I change the date.
I use ```hide.datetimepicker``` instead

Comment: The downside of this , is that the above yields current date/time , if no value is set.

Answer (score 6):

In case anybody was experiencing the same trouble as me (using bootstrap v4 `https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/`), and wanting the date at the time the picker is closed, here is the code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
    $('#datetimepicker').on("datetimepicker.hide", function (e) {
        console.log(moment(e.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));
    });
});
```

Note that in this case, `datetimepicker` comes before `hide`, which is different to `change` coming before `datetimepicker`. Using `hide.datetimepicker` will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe i am wrong but the way I interpret **"Note All options are accessed via the data attribute"** it says to access the functions in the following format

`$("#YOU_SELECTOR").data('DateTimePicker').FUNCTION();`

if you try to `console.log($("#YOU_SELECTOR").data('DateTimePicker'));`

You will see that it prints all those functions that it says `are accessible` via `data` attribute, a few I am printing below

```
{
    "destroy": function () {
        H(), I(), i.widget.remove(), i.element.removeData("DateTimePicker"), i.component && i.component.removeData("DateTimePicker")
    },
    "show": function (a) {
        if (!l().prop("disabled")) {
            if (i.options.useCurrent && "" === l().val()) {
                if (1 !== i.options.minuteStepping) {
                    var c = b(),
                        d = i.options.minuteStepping;
                    c.minutes(Math.round(c.minutes() / d) * d % 60).seconds(0), i.setValue(c.format(i.format))
                } else i.setValue(b().format(i.format));
                o("", a.type)
            }
            a && "click" === a.type && i.isInput && i.widget.hasClass("picker-open") || (i.widget.hasClass("picker-open") ? (i.widget.hide(), i.widget.removeClass("picker-open")) : (i.widget.show(), i.widget.addClass("picker-open")), i.height = i.component ? i.component.outerHeight() : i.element.outerHeight(), n(), i.element.trigger({
                type: "dp.show",
                date: b(i.date)
            }), G(), a && B(a))
        }
    },
    "disable": function () {
        var a = l();
        a.prop("disabled") || (a.prop("disabled", !0), H())
    },
    "enable": function () {
        var a = l();
        a.prop("disabled") && (a.prop("disabled", !1), F())
    },
    "hide": function () {
        var a, c, d = i.widget.find(".collapse");
        for (a = 0; a < d.length; a++)
            if (c = d.eq(a).data("collapse"), c && c.transitioning) return;
        i.widget.hide(), i.widget.removeClass("picker-open"), i.viewMode = i.startViewMode, E(), i.element.trigger({
            type: "dp.hide",
            date: b(i.date)
        }), I()
    },
    "setValue": function (a) {
        b.locale(i.options.language), a ? i.unset = !1 : (i.unset = !0, K()), a = b.isMoment(a) ? a.locale(i.options.language) : a instanceof Date ? b(a) : b(a, i.format, i.options.useStrict), a.isValid() ? (i.date = a, K(), i.viewDate = b({
            y: i.date.year(),
            M: i.date.month()
        }), t(), x()) : p(a)
    },
    "getDate": function () {
        return i.unset ? null : b(i.date)
    },
    "setDate": function (a) {
        var c = b(i.date);
        i.setValue(a ? a : null), o(c, "function")
    },
    "setDisabledDates": function (a) {
        i.options.disabledDates = O(a), i.viewDate && q()
    },
    "setEnabledDates": function (a) {
        i.options.enabledDates = O(a), i.viewDate && q()
    },
    "setMaxDate": function (a) {
        void 0 !== a && (i.options.maxDate = b.isMoment(a) || a instanceof Date ? b(a) : b(a, i.format, i.options.useStrict), i.viewDate && q())
    },
    "setMinDate": function (a) {
        void 0 !== a && (i.options.minDate = b.isMoment(a) || a instanceof Date ? b(a) : b(a, i.format, i.options.useStrict), i.viewDate && q())
    }
    .............. and more,
```

see below calling `getDate()` in the demo via a click of a link. you can check after changing the date to verify.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var picker = $('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker();

  //console.log(picker.datetimepicker('data-view-date'));
  //console.log($('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker('data-show'));

  $("#tog").on('click', function() {
    //console.log($('#datetimepicker7').data('DateTimePicker'));
    console.log($('#datetimepicker7').data('DateTimePicker').getDate());
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.1.4/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.1.4/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />




<div class="container">
  <div class='col-md-5'>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker7" data-target-input="nearest">
        <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker7" />
        <span class="input-group-addon" data-target="#datetimepicker7" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#." id="tog">toggle</a>
</div>
```